# Find an equation of the tangent line to the graph of

Tags: derivatives

Find an equation of the tangent line to the graph of $F(x)=x^2$ at

1. $(3, 9)$
2. $(-1, 1)$
3. $(10, 100)$

Comment: Have you any ideas what to do?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, could you tell us what you've tried, or what's your thought?

Comment: Step 1: Find the derivative of $F(x)=x^2$ with respect to $x$ as a function of $x$.  Step 2: Interpret what the derivative represents.  By plugging in specific values of $x$ into the derivative, you get the slope of the original function at that $x$-value.  Step 3: Describe the line using what information you have (points and slopes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do the first one you can apply it to the other two.

The slope of the tangent line is the derivative of $x^2 = 2x$

At point $(3, 9)$ the slope is $6$

The equation of the line going through $(3, 9$) with slope $6$ is:

$y = 6x + b$ where $b$ is the y intercept

$9 = 6(3) + b$

$b = 9 - 18 = -9$

Equation is: $y = 6x - 9$